# Geoservers communicating with other Geoservers

Tags: geoserver, geonetwork

I am able to connect to multiple Geoservers using the Geonetwork but is it possible for two Geoservers to communicate with each other without the Geonetwork?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup got the answer. It is cascading service and also it's main advantage,

1. If you don’t manage or have access to the remote WMS, you can now manage its output as if it were local.
2. Even if the remote WMS is not GeoServer, you can use GeoServer features to treat its output (watermarking, decoration, printing, etc).

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html